# What does the ssl_version set as nil fallback to in ruby OpenSSL

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl

We have asked to by our payment provider to upgrade the SSL version to TLS from SSLv3 citing [poodle](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA14-290A) attack

Currently I see the **ssl_version** been set as `nil` in Ruby `net/https` library what I'm trying to understand is when **ssl_version** is set `nil` ***what does it translate to?*** (or  fallback to ?)

Reading through [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49106/let-openssl-decide-which-tls-protocol-version-is-used-by-default) make me feel that it upto OpenSSL to decide the ssl_version(protocol)  to use

It also mention by setting [`:auto`](https://github.com/aef/httpclient/commit/1753454f5d2c45d34f72eb52b456216ce4a95774#diff-2f54812a2786a9c04529e1b7236542ebR39) always make sure it take the highest available protocol

Can anyone share some light on it.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 2.1.3 uses `SSLv23` as a default. You can check it in your irb console:

```
> require 'openssl'
# => true
> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS
# => {
# =>     :ssl_version => "SSLv23",
# =>     :verify_mode => 1,
# =>     :ciphers     => "ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW",
# =>     :options     => -2147482625
# => }
```

Btw there is another constant that tells you all available SSL/TLS methods:

```
> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS
# => [
# =>     [ 0] :TLSv1,
# =>     [ 1] :TLSv1_server,
# =>     [ 2] :TLSv1_client,
# =>     [ 3] :TLSv1_2,
# =>     [ 4] :TLSv1_2_server,
# =>     [ 5] :TLSv1_2_client,
# =>     [ 6] :TLSv1_1,
# =>     [ 7] :TLSv1_1_server,
# =>     [ 8] :TLSv1_1_client,
# =>     [ 9] :SSLv3,
# =>     [10] :SSLv3_server,
# =>     [11] :SSLv3_client,
# =>     [12] :SSLv23,
# =>     [13] :SSLv23_server,
# =>     [14] :SSLv23_client
# => ]
```

see: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLContext.html#constants-list

Comment: Thanks a ton 1) question though I believe with that I don't have to worry changing the SSL_version explicitly, If the server return Hello Message in TLSv1 the openssl would infact then use the desired TLSv1 protocol to communicate hence forth am I correct

Comment: The above reference is drawn from [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg75398.html)